'Unknown Collation' error on upgrade
Updating  craft 5.2.8 => 5.5.7
php craft update craft

yields

create table {{%sso_identities}} ...Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]:
General error: 1273 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' The SQL
being executed was: CREATE TABLE sso_identities (
provider varchar(255) NOT NULL,
identityId varchar(255) NOT NULL,
userId int(11) NOT NULL,
dateCreated datetime(0) NOT NULL,
dateUpdated datetime(0) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(provider, identityId, userId) ) ENGINE = InnoDb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE =
utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
(/home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:676)

Ideas how to resolve? Do I need to change collation of the table in question? It so, how would I do that?

Your database server is telling you that it doesn't know the utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci collation. You need to configure a collation that your database server actually supports.
You can set the collation either in your config/db.php or as an environment variable CRAFT_DB_COLLATION, usually through your .env file.
If you leave this setting out, Craft will use an appropriate default. To solve your issue, you can simply remove the explicit collation that you're setting in your config and let Craft figure it out. Or set the correct collation depending on your database:
MySQL

For MySQL <8.0, use utf8mb4_general_ci.
Upgrading to MySQL 8 and sticking with utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci is the better solution.

MariaDB
Use uca1400_ai_ci if you use a recent version of MariaDB, or utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci for older versions.

Craft says it's using MariaDB 10.5.22. Should I still make that change? @moritzlost

@4midory Ah, in this case you need a different collation, MariaDB supports different collations than MySQL. Keep in mind that MariaDB isn't a drop-in replacement for MySQL anymore, so you need to configure your system for the database server you're intending to use. I've updated my answer with recommendations for both MySQL and MariaDB.

@moriztlost I tried all three options in my .env (no collation, uca1400_ai_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci) but Craft failed on each one. Do I need to convert to MySQL?
